# how to perform prop.test (comparing two groups) row-wise on a large data set

Tags: r

As I can't adapt answers already given to the subject to my special problem:

I have a data set:

data.csv:

> col1  col2    col3    col4
>
> 8600  64  1e+06   1e+06
>
> 9000  8999    1e+06   1e+06
>
> ...   ... ... ...

I import the data and run prop.test to check for significant differences between values in col1 and col2 (n1 and n2 are the total numbers of the sample size).

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep="\t", header=TRUE, dec = ",") 
x1 <- data$col1
x2 <- data$col2
n1 <- data$col3
n2 <- data$col4

pval <- prop.test(c(x1,x2),c(n1,n2))
pval$p.value
```

does not give me p.value for all rows:

```
summary(pval)
```

gives:

```
   Length Class  Mode     
statistic     1    -none- numeric  
parameter     1    -none- numeric  
p.value       1    -none- numeric  
estimate    200    -none- numeric  
null.value    0    -none- NULL     
conf.int      0    -none- NULL     
alternative   1    -none- character
method        1    -none- character
data.name     1    -none- character
```

If I do it row-wise it seems to work for that row

```
pval2 <- prop.test(c(x1[1],x2[1]),c(n1[1],n2[1]))

pval2$p.value
summary(pval2)
```

gives:

```
Length Class  Mode     
statistic   1      -none- numeric  
parameter   1      -none- numeric  
p.value     1      -none- numeric  
estimate    2      -none- numeric  
null.value  0      -none- NULL     
conf.int    2      -none- numeric  
alternative 1      -none- character
method      1      -none- character
data.name   1      -none- character
```

obviously I don't want to do it for all 100 rows manually.
Any suggestions how to do prop.test row wise and getting p.value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By modifying your successful attempt, the following should work:

```
ans <- lapply(seq_along(x1), function(i) prop.test(c(x1[i],x2[i]),c(n1[i],n2[i])))
```

Comment: This variant works. But how do I isolate each p.value.

Answer (score 1):

Since prop.test takes various forms of inputs and I am not all that familiar with it, I can't quite tell which one you are trying to use, so I won't evaluate if you are using the stat properly.  But, I will tell you 2 ways to avoid doing the test for each row manually.

I use and think data table, so please excuse me if this is confusing for you.
The code below is not tested, I'm afraid.  My R session is busy.

```
require(data.table) 
##read the data into a data table.   
data <- data.table(read.csv("data.csv", sep="\t", header=TRUE, dec = ","))
## add an id, identifying each row.
data[,id:=seq(1:(.N))]
## do prop.test for each row.
data[,prop.test(c(col1,col2),c(col3,col4)),by="id"]
```

If that is not for you, you can try an lapply.

```
a <- c(1:nrow(data))
myrowprop <- function(i) {
    prop.test(c(x1[i],x2[i]),c(n1[i],n2[i]))
}
ListofResults <- lapply(a,myrowprop)
```

Comment: first variant throws an error. The second one works just fine. Same problem as above (answer of AEBilgrau): How do I isolate just the p.values?